# Passing ids between activities

Tags: android-intent, android-activity

I recently began programming in Java Eclipse....

I am making a bmi calculator but I'm having some trouble with my activities.

I have a settings activity and a calculator activity and I my intention with the setting activity is that when u check a radiobutton it changes something in the calculator activity..

E.g - When u press the Unit radiobutton in the settings activity, textviews in calculator activity changes.....

I'm pretty sure I can solve this in 2 ways - the Application object or trying to pass the id with an intent but I'm not sure how to make either of them work so I need your help!

I wonder if it's required that the calculator already have been opened and created for the ids to pass or not....

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Where is the code example you require help with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Shared preferences**

If you want to store the settings permanently, the best way is to use [`SharedPreferences`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref). Take a look at the website for an example of how to use it. Shared preferences are accessible from all activities of the same application. You could even share them with other applications. Basically you would store the new value in the preferences, and then read them in `onResume()` of the other activity. The drawback of shared preferences is, that you can store primitives and strings only (e.g. int, long, String, ...).

**Intents**

If you want to use Intents to pass temporary data to the other activity, you would want to call one of the various [`Intent.putExtra()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html). Methods which behave like a `HashMap`, i.e. you provide a key and value. The other activity can then retrieve the values from the Intent using one of the getter methods.

**Application object**

Using an own implementation of the [`Application`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) class and storing values there is as well possible. But usually not required for most applications. You will have to extend the `Application` class and specify its name in the `<application>` tag, [`android:name`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#nm) attribute of your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

A not very reliable way would be to simply store the values in `public static` fields of the activity and access them from the other activity. However, you should prefer one of the other methods.

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer! I'll try to use shared preferences but I'm not sure how to do it if u want the IDs... Do you have to use an integer and then set the ID in the next activity or how does it work?